# How to truncate an NSString 'x' characters after a certain character is found

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, truncate

Say I have an `NSString`, it represents a price that otherwise would be a double of course. I am trying to make it truncate the string at the hundredths place so it is something like `19.99` instead of `19.99412092414` for example. Is there a way, once detecting the decimal like so...

```
if ([price rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        // Decimal point exists, truncate string at the hundredths.
    }
```

for me to cut off the string 2 characters after that ".", without separating it into an array then doing a max size truncate on the `decimal` before finally reassembling them?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is string manipulation, not math, so the resulting value won't be rounded:

```
NSRange range = [price rangeOfString:@"."];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSInteger index = MIN(range.location+2, price.length-1);
    NSString *truncated = [price substringToIndex:index];
}
```

This is mostly string manipulation, tricking NSString into doing that math for us:

```
NSString *roundedPrice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [price floatValue]];
```

Or you might consider keeping all numeric values as numbers, thinking of strings as just a way to present them to the user.  For that, use NSNumberFormatter:

```
NSNumber *priceObject = // keep these sorts values as objects
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];                
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

 NSString *presentMeToUser = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:priceObject];
 // you could also keep price as a float, "boxing" it at the end with:
 // [NSNumber numberWithFloat:price];
```